# html and css rocket animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was doing the following tutorial on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAewuQPMFI8&t=106s

```css
@charset "utf-8";

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scene
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #01070A;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.scene i
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -250px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.50);
    animation: animateStars linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animateStars {
    0%
    {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateY(200vh);
    }
}
.scene .rocket
{
    position: relative;
    animation: animate 0.2s, ease infinite;;
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%;
    {
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    50%;
    {
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }
}
.scene .rocket::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff,transparent);
}
.scene .rocket::after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff,transparent);
    filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rocket Animation Effect</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scene" >
        <div class="rocket">
        <img src="rocket.png" width="72" height="99" alt=""/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function star() {
            let count = 50;
            let scene = document.querySelector('.scene');
            let i = 0;
            while(i > count){
                let star = document.createElement('i');
                let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
                
                let duration = Math.random() * 1;
                let h = Math.random() * 100;
                
                star.style.left = x + 'px';
                star.style.width = 1 'px';
                star.style.height = h 'px';
                star.style.animationDuration = duration + 's';
                
                scene.appendChild(star);
                i++
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the code was supposed to show a flying rocket controlled by the mouse, but the code didn't turn out it showed on the tutorial. If anyone can tell my what  i did wrong, i would appreciate it greatly.

PLease and thank you.

Comment: I have corrected your code. Everything works well now. Check please. I have listed all errors.

Comment: Please note that "code didn't turn out" is very vague. It would be preferable if you could tell us more precisely what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

You got problem with your js

```
star.style.width = 1 'px';
star.style.height = h 'px';
```

Should be

```
star.style.width = 1 + 'px';
star.style.height = h + 'px';
```

Example:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scene
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #01070A;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.scene i
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -250px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.50);
    animation: animateStars linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animateStars {
    0%
    {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateY(200vh);
    }
}
.scene .rocket
{
    position: relative;
    animation: animate 0.2s, ease infinite;;
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%;
    {
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    50%;
    {
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }
}
.scene .rocket::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff,transparent);
}
.scene .rocket::after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff,transparent);
    filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rocket Animation Effect</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scene" >
        <div class="rocket">
        <img src="rocket.png" width="72" height="99" alt=""/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function star() {
            let count = 50;
            let scene = document.querySelector('.scene');
            let i = 0;
            while(i > count){
                let star = document.createElement('i');
                let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
                
                let duration = Math.random() * 1;
                let h = Math.random() * 100;
                
                star.style.left = x + 'px';
                star.style.width = 1 + 'px';
                star.style.height = h + 'px';
                star.style.animationDuration = duration + 's';
                
                scene.appendChild(star);
                i++
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have had errors in your code.

You confused the equal sign:

```
while(i < count)
```

You had it like this:

```
while(i > count)
```

There was no "+" sign in the lines:

```
star.style.width = 1 'px';
star.style.height = h 'px';
```

Also, you needed to center the exhaust rocket. In the css code, you also made mistakes when you specified `px` instead of `%`, in transform rules: `translateX (-50%);`

```js
function stars() {
            let count = 50;
            let scene = document.querySelector('.scene');
            let i = 0;
            while(i < count){
                let star = document.createElement('i');
                let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
                
                let duration = Math.random() * 1;
                let h = Math.random() * 100;
                
                star.style.left = x + 'px';
                star.style.width = 1 + 'px';
                star.style.height = h + 'px';
                star.style.animationDuration = duration + 's';
                
                scene.appendChild(star);
                i++;
            }
}

stars();
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scene
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #01070A;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.scene .rocket
{
    position: relative;
    animation: animate 0.2s ease infinite;
}

.scene .rocket::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff,transparent);
}
.scene .rocket::after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff,transparent);
    filter: blur(20px);
}

.scene i
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -250px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    animation: animateStars linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateStars {
    0%
    {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateY(200vh);
    }
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%, 100%
    {
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    50%
    {
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="scene">
        <div class="rocket">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/yd3IE9aeueXYyfo94zyvaIlkS-aRhsvUHWomCsWjvw6RmYN96aQ7WR7hLplxgeV14z7ALWS8owmsew=w1920-h969" width="72" height="99" alt=""/> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```